# Why is the production build of my app receiving pushes from the development cert/host combo?

Tags: ios, certificate, apple-push-notifications, production

I build my app in release mode, and I expect the new host to be gateway.push.apple.com and to use my production certificates, right?

Well!  I was debugging for hours trying to figure out why my app wasn't getting it, and guess what?  I switch it over to development certs and sandbox host, and I get a push!  On my release-built app!

I must be missing something.  They did away with entitlements.plist a while ago right?

Any idea why my release build is working with dev certs/host (which it should not) and not prod certs/host?

Comment: If you provision is using as developer, it uses sandbox.
If you are using distribution one, it uses production

Comment: Did you try your dev certs with sandbox? Is it possible that you switched the filenames?

Comment: fattomhk, What do you mean "if your provision is using as..." I'm building as 'release'.  Is there an option in the actual provisioning profile that says dev or prod?

Comment: Nick C, The dev certs only work with sandbox.  What I'm saying is that the dev certs and sandbox are what is pushing to what I THOUGHT was a production build.  Make sense?  It's confusing, sorry if I'm explaining it poorly :(

Comment: Oh, stupid me! I forgot about the tabs in the provisioning profile..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot about the tabs when making the provisioning profile.  I did make it under the development tab. (I should have made this provisioning profile under distribution) This was a bad mistake.  Thanks for the help!